# Why doesn't CORS apply? in gcp app-engine

Tags: website, web, google-app-engine, cors

I am trying to post marvin JS on the site.

There is no problem with the iframe and the function itself, but a problem occurs when using additional functions.

When the current page is executed, the following message appears.

[Error] SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "-mysitedomain.appspot.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

and

Blocked a frame with origin "https://storage.googleapis.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://-mysitedomain.appspot.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Is this a CORS related issue?

I additionally added CORS to the bucket but it doesn't solve the problem.

my CORS setting file:

```
[
    {
        "origin": ["*"],
        "method": ["*"],
        "responseHeader": ["*"],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is a CORS error. I don't know the format that your CORS settings are in, but you should check to be sure they're correct. If you capture some requests and responses, you can check the CORS headers to work out where the problem is.

Comment: This issue is not related to CORS, So I understand that you are updating the ifram DOM which is not possible to do. An iframe can't be accessed and modified from another website. Please have a look into the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/8791788)